# How to install a plugin offline in Redmine 2.6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am trying to install the following plugin: https://github.com/arkhitech/redmine_timesheet_plugin on an offline installaton. It seems that the plugin installation is trying to download the earth to install it. Is there a canonical way to do it?

Redmine versio is 2.6.0, rails version is 4.1.6, and Ruby version is 2.0.0.